# Basic smart contract to transfer a fixed amount of Ether from my wallet to another

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I am trying to build a basic smart contract that sends a fixed amount of ether from one wallet to another. I am trying something like like this:

```
contract Autopayment {
    
    address  payable recipient = 0xBfD0a1880fBd2c45093c974E611Ea0A23031536f ;
    uint256 amount = 0.01 ether;

    function sendEth() public payable {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

but when I invoke the sendEth() function it gives the error:
**from solidity:ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing in your code is that an address payable needs to be initialised with payable(). The rest should work, as long as you send ether along with the call to sendEth() function.

Your code should look like this:

```
contract Autopayment {
    
    address  payable recipient = payable(0xBfD0a1880fBd2c45093c974E611Ea0A23031536f);
    uint256 amount = 0.01 ether;

    function sendEth() public payable {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible if I want the contract to transfer the ether automatically to the wallet upon deployment without providing any user input or performing any other action after deployment. Should I call the function sendEth() in the constructor for that to work that way?

Comment: Exactly, make the constructor payable and deploy with some ether sent along.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you put an extra line of code. The correct code would as below:

EG.

```
contract Autopayment{
   address  payable recipient = payable(0xBfD0a1880fBd2c45093c974E611Ea0A23031536f);
   uint256 amount = 0.01 ether;

   function sendEth() public payable {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
    }
    
}
```